# Inserting values to NULL rows based on the closest date that is not NULL and is earlier than the row date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, insert

I'm getting foreign exchange rates from Riksbanken API. This API doesn't give values for holidays, saturdays or sundays. So my FX rates is empty for those days. However when I convert currencies in my tables I do a join based on date & currency. So in a case where I have a transaction on a Sunday then I can't convert it because that is NULL, and transaction amount * NULL = NULL.

Basically this is my situation:

```
DECLARE @fxrates TABLE(cur varchar(5), rate decimal, rowDate date);
INSERT INTO @fxrates VALUES
 ('EUR',10.40,'2020-04-30')
, ('EUR',10.50,'2020-05-01')
, ('EUR',NULL,'2020-05-02')
, ('EUR',NULL,'2020-05-03')
, ('EUR',10.60,'2020-05-04')
, ('EUR',10.70,'2020-05-05')


DECLARE @value TABLE(cur varchar(5), amount decimal, rowDate date);
INSERT INTO @value VALUES
 ('EUR',1500,'2020-04-30')
, ('EUR',9000,'2020-05-01')
, ('EUR',1000,'2020-05-02')
, ('EUR',300,'2020-05-03')
, ('EUR',160,'2020-05-04')
, ('EUR',170,'2020-05-05')


--How I convert the values
select v.amount * fx.rate as [Converted amount] from @fxrates fx 
JOIN @value v
on fx.cur=v.cur
and fx.rowDate=v.rowDate
```

My solution for this would be to always replace NULL with the "earlier" value, based on date. However I have no idea how that logic would be implemented in SQL. So my fxrates table would look like this:

```
 ('EUR',10.40,'2020-04-30')
 ('EUR',10.50,'2020-05-01')
 ('EUR',10.50,'2020-05-02')
 ('EUR',10.50,'2020-05-03')
 ('EUR',10.60,'2020-05-04')
 ('EUR',10.70,'2020-05-05')
```

Would replacing the NULL values be the best approach moving forward? And how can I achieve that using SQL?

Comment: More importantly - declaring a column as decimal is a problem. Without specifying precision and scale, your columns use the default values which are `decimal(18,0)`. It cannot store a number like 10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery here to find the most recent non `NULL` price for every date which be missing a price:

```
SELECT
    cur,
    COALESCE(rate,
        (SELECT TOP 1 f2.rate FROM @fxrates f2
         WHERE f2.cur = f1.cur AND f2.rowDate < f1.rowDate AND f2.rate IS NOT NULL
         ORDER BY f2.rowdate DESC)
    ) AS rate,
    rowDate
FROM @fxrates f1
ORDER BY
    cur,
    rowDate;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Comment: @Anton There is probably a way to do this using analytic functions, which might be a bit less code.  Not sure on performance, in all cases, a reverse lookup has to be done to find the closest non `NULL` rate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `CROSS APPLY` to get the latest exchange rate that is valid before or at the transaction date.

```
SELECT v.amount * fx.rate AS [Converted amount]
       FROM @value v
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                                fx.rate
                                FROM @fxrates fx
                                WHERE fx.cur = v.cur
                                      AND fx.rowdate <= v.rowdate
                                      AND fx.rate IS NOT NULL
                                ORDER BY fx.rowdate DESC) fx;
```

Comment: Nice! This solution is a little different than the other one, but actually serves my purpose better, since in some cases I don't have all dates in the table. Unfortunately I already accepted the other answer since it did solve the problem I was asking for. Thanks for the help, this is the solution that will be best for me though!